# How to write explicit unicode to XML file in Python 3.5?

Tags: xml, unicode, python-3.5

I just want to create an XML file that does something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    jos&#233;
</Response>
```

I'm trying to write josé like this.

```
str("josé".encode())
```

But I get this written in the file:

```
b'jos\xc3\xa9'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an XML document as a Unicode string then to write it to a file so that you would see `jos&#233;` instead of `josé`, you could use `xmlcharrefreplace` error handler:

```
with open('response.xml', 'w', encoding='ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace') as file:
    file.write(xml_text)
```

If you use a library to construct an XML document (recommended) then use the appropriate API to save the object to a file e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('Response')
root.text = 'josé'
with open('response.xml', 'wb') as file:
    ET.ElementTree(root).write(file, xml_declaration=True)
```

#### response.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<Response>jos&#233;</Response>
```

See [`ElementTree.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).